# elem as this in function

Tags: jquery

I have jquery function:

```
function handleSplittingPrices() {
    var customerId = $(this).val();
    loadSplittingPrices(customerId);
}
```

I want to execute it with elem as "this":

```
var elem=$('...');
handleSplittingPrices() <-- here elem will be this
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`call` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
handleSplittingPrices.call(elem);
```

Note that `elem` is a jQuery object, not a DOM element, so you won't need to call `$` inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
handleSplittingPrices.call(elem);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't.  Obviously you don't know what "this" is for.

function handleSplittingPrices(elem) {
    var customerId = $(elem).val();
    loadSplittingPrices(customerId);
}

var elem=$('...');
handleSplittingPrices(elem);

Wow. Now wasn't that simpler than trying to define the whole concept of Object Oriented programming?

Comment: If you're going to be condescending, you should really first make sure you're correct.